# IE6 - show swf animation

Tags: html, animation, internet-explorer-6

IE6 don`t show animation:

```
          <object width="456" height="315">
            <param name="movie" value="animacija.swf">
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
            <embed src="animacija.swf" width="456" height="315">
            </embed>
          </object>
```

"Your security settings do not allow websites to use ActiveX controls installed on your computer."

Other animation show normaly on other websites.

Comment: It sounds like its specific to your install of IE6, its a hateful piece of software but it can handle Flash.  Assuming the code is fine (I don't have an IE6 machine to try it out) - it sounds like you (or your organisation) have manually changed the security settings on your PC.... See if you can set them back to default.

Comment: The error message says it all -- the security settings in IE6 are set up not to allow activeX controls (of which Flash is one). This is generally a good thing to do with IE6, as ActiveX is a major security hole for the browser. Whether the error happens or not is not an IE6 problem; it will differ for different users, according to how they have the security settings configured. Not much you can do about it, short of changing the settings (of course you can't control how your users set up their browser). But overall I'd agree with @Codecraft - drop IE6 support for your site if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks, I am satisfied with the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your HTML-file locally? That can be a problem. Try uploading the HTML & swf-file to the web and check if the problem still occcurs.

Comment: Yes, i do locally. Why it is a problem?

Comment: I dont't know exactly. It has something to do with the security model in IE6. I only know that I had tje same issue at work before we updated to IE8